# Calculating cost distance in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I need to calculate cost distance for each cell in my raster (bounding box: Sumatera island) to points (palm oil mills), with slope as its cost. The cost layer (slope) has float data type (val: 0-90), and I can't seem to get the right code to make the variable cost calculation works.

```js
// Add features
var sumatera = ee.FeatureCollection("users/putraditama/sumatera"); // Sumatera island boundary (polygon)
var po_mills = ee.FeatureCollection("users/putraditama/po_mills"); // palm oil mills (points)

// Add raster
var elev = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003");

// Clip elev to Sumatera boundary
var elevsmrt = elev.clip(sumatera);

// Get slope
var slopesmrt = ee.Terrain.slope(elevsmrt);

// Create a source image (palm oil mill=1, others=0)
var sources = ee.Image().toByte().paint(po_mills, 1);

// Mask the sources image with itself.
sources = sources.updateMask(sources);

// The cost data is generated from slope 
var cover = slopesmrt.select(0);

// Variable cost
var cost =
  cover.eq(0-10).or(cover.eq(11-20)).or(cover.eq(21-30))
      .multiply(1).add(
  cover.eq(31-40).or(cover.eq(41-50)).or(cover.eq(51-60))
      .multiply(2).add(
  cover.eq(61-70).or(cover.eq(71-80)).or(cover.eq(81-90))
      .multiply(3)));

// Compute the cumulative cost to traverse the land cover.
var cumulativeCost = cost.cumulativeCost({
  source: sources,
  maxDistance: 1000 * 1000 // 1000 kilometers
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Changed the variable cost script into this:

```js
var cost = 
  cover.gt(0).and(cover.lt(30))
      .multiply(1).add(
  cover.gt(31).and(cover.lt(60))
      .multiply(2).add(
  cover.gt(61).and(cover.lt(90))
      .multiply(3)));
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as the correct one using the grey/green tick to the left.